Verilog: How to substitute 8'b with a localparam, $bits or something else?
In the sample code 'localparam CMD_MSB = 7;' is created in a separate project file. The other three lines are in my design file. CMD_MSB could change values without my immediate knowledge. Is there a way to use a localparam, $bits or something else in my design file for the 8'b in the last line to handle changes of the CMD_MSB value?
localparam CMD_MSB = 7; // Project file

logic [CMD_MSB:0] cmd;  // My design file
logic wr_cmd, cmd_vld; // My design file
assign cmd_vld = wr_cmd & (cmd == 8'b0_01_???_01); // My design file
                                  ^^^


You can use a concatenation to build up the decode value something like this:
module tb();
  
  localparam CMD_MSB = 7; // Project file
  localparam OTHER_BITS_1 = 4'hf;  
  localparam OTHER_BITS_2 = 4'hf;  
  localparam USED_AS_DECODE = {CMD_MSB,OTHER_BITS_1,OTHER_BITS_2};  

  logic [CMD_MSB:0] cmd;  // My design file
  logic wr_cmd, cmd_vld; // My design file
  
  assign cmd_vld = wr_cmd & (cmd == USED_AS_DECODE); // My design file
  
endmodule


There's no need to do anything as Verilog will implicitly extend operands of a bitwise-and to the width of the largest operand. Since you have unsigned types, your literal will be 0-padded.
If you want to be explicit, I suggest using a typedef and a cast.
localparam CMD_MSB = 7; // Project file

typedef logic [CMD_MSB:0] CMD_t;
CMD_t cmd;  // My design file
logic wr_cmd, cmd_vld; // My design file
assign cmd_vld = wr_cmd & (cmd ==? CMD_t'('b0_01_???_01)); 

I also suggest using the wildcard equality operator for don't-care comparisons. This makes sure X's on the LHS are not interpreted incorrectly as don't-cares. Only xz? on the RHS are treated that way.
